# PHP XML How to extract the element where name= using simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I have an XML file I need to extract only certain elements from. And at some point the XML file could be updated and completely change the order which the elements appear in - but the elements contain a name= setting.

```
<element>
 <sub name='this1'>value</sub>
 <sub name='this2'>value</sub>
 <sub name='this3'>value</sub>
 <sub name='this4'>value</sub>     
</element>
```

I need to extract the values say for this2 and this4.

But at some stage, new sub elements may be added, changing the order. So I can't use:

```
$xml->element->sub[2]
```

Example below:

```
<element>
 <sub name='this0'>value</sub>
 <sub name='this1'>value</sub>
 <sub name='this2'>value</sub>
 <sub name='this3'>value</sub>     
 <sub name='this4'>value</sub>    
</element>
```

So sub[2] would then become this1 instead of this2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a XPath query, e.g. `$myXml->xpath("/sub[@name=this1]")`. Read more about Xpath here http://php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: So that's almost what I need. But I need to extract the value contained within the element itself. So `this2` should be `value`

Comment: `$value = current($myXml->xpath("/sub[@name=this1]");` This will only work nicely if the query returns only a single element, the rest would be lost.